# Bulk rename files containing underscores in Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, batch-processing, file-rename, batch-rename

I want to rename a batch of files with the names example_P1.csv to example.csv in a folder in command prompt.

How do I achieve this?

I can't get any success with the following command:

```
ren *_P1.csv *.csv
```

I want to remove _P1 from all those files.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a simple `rename`. Try this instead:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*_P1.csv) do (
  set "basename=%%~nf"
  ren "%%~ff" "!basename:~0,-3!%%~xf"
)
```

Comment: +1, But `_P1` could appear in multiple locations within the name. Better to use `"!basename:~-3!%%~xf"`. Also will need to toggle delayed expansion on/off within loop if any names contain `!` character.